# ESP32 MQTT error

Tags: mqtt, esp32

I have been trying to connect my ESP32 board to my laptop via MQTT. I have installed Mosquitto MQTT broker on my laptop but I fail to connect my ESP32 every time. This is the test code I am using to check MQTT connection.

```c
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
const char* ssid = "......";              //WiFi Name
const char* password = "......";      //WiFi Password
const char* server= "xxx.xxx.xx.xx";    //RPi or Machine IP on which the broker is

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

int setup_WiFi(){
  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
  client.connect("esp32");      
  if (client.connect("esp32")){                 
      Serial.println("connected");
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.println(client.state());
    }
    return 0;
}

int reconnect() {
  unsigned long startAttemptTime = millis();
  while (!client.connected())  
    {
    Serial.println("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect("esp32")){
      Serial.println("connected");
    } 
    else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.println(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int send_mqtt(){
  setup_WiFi();
  char sss[15]="Hello World";
   if (!client.connected()){
    reconnect();
  } 
  client.publish("esp32/test", sss);    //send message
  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  Serial.println("Sent");
  return 0;
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  client.setServer(server, 1883);   //mqtt server details
  setup_WiFi();
  reconnect();
    }

void loop() {
  send_mqtt();
  delay(10000);     //Wait 10 secs before next transmission
}
```

But each time I get the error

> failed, rc=-2

I have been trying to do the same for the past 2 months or so but to no success. Meanwhile, I have searched the internet extensively, to see what was it that I am doing wrong. I make sure that both the devices are on the same LAN.

Comment: I missed mentioning that I have opened firewall settings. I am able to send a message from localhost to localhost but outside that not able to connect not even an android

Comment: is your esp32 on the same network or are you trying to come in from an outside address.

Comment: Also, is there any thing of interest in the broker logs on your laptop?

Comment: @Chad G yes, both the ESP32 and the laptop are on the same network

Comment: What OS are we talking about and be more specific with how your firewall rules look like and a copy of mosquitto.conf . The sparse info you have given is just turning this into a guessing game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mosquitto is only local (on the same computer) if no custom config is used, do you use a custom config?

What OS do you have on the laptop?

Under listener in the config example found here:  [mosquitto/mosquitto.conf](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/mosquitto.conf).

On row 216 add `listener 1883 0.0.0.0` to allow outside of the computer connections.